# What is most efficient way to find ‘inverse' of getting all records that match particular criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find the most efficient way to find ‘inverse' of getting all records that match particular criteria
I.e. find all predefined criteria from a set that a particular record matches

I have a table of 'target' criteria that has many records - each built using a querybuilder javascript component - so each target record has its criteria stored as a json string in a field.

I also have a standard 'person' table

It is straight forward to query how many people fit a particular target.
What I am trying to do is get all targets that match a particular person

Is there a more efficient way than just running each target's criteria against a person?

Open to suggestions beyond just sql - e.g. caching , hashing or building up some kind of lookup table/file

## Edit:

Hopefully tables below clarify this issue. If I parsed and ran the 'Good Eyesight' target criteria I would expect to return both Bob and Sue

But I want to know that Bob matches the 'Young People' and 'Good Eyesight' target. I will have thousands of users and probably up to 50 active targets.

```
Table 1: Person
ID    Name    Age   Fav_Vegetable
---------------------------------
1     Bob     20    Carrot
2     Sue     40    Carrot
```

```
Table 2: Target
ID    Name             Criteria_JSON
---------------------------------
1     Young People     {"rule": "young_age", "selectedOperator": "<","selectedOperand": "Age","value": "30"}
2     Old People       {"rule": "old_age", "selectedOperator": ">","selectedOperand": "Age","value": "30"}
3     Good Eyesight    {"rule": "vegetable","selectedOperator": "equals","selectedOperand": "Fav_Vegetable","value": "Carrot"}
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: @Mark I understand the part about parsing "Good Eyesight" and getting Bob and Sue. But the next sentence I don't understand. Do you want to use the result of the first query (Bob, Sue) and get all targets that match all of them? Show an example of the desired result. Thinking about it again, you won't be able to get the matching targets without running the queries. So you'd have to run all queries, then join.

Comment: @Mark . . . .You pretty much need to go through all the criteria and all the rows.  You might be able to increase performance -- say by running in parallel, but I don't see any other approach other than brute force for the general problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Agreed - and elaborated on in answer I have posted below in terms of performance

Answer (score 0):

The answer I have come up with is to run all targets against all people and maintain an index type table of the results.

i.e. have a table TargetIndex with columns targetId, personId

Then when I need to know the targets for a particular person I can just check against the TargetIndex table rather than rerunning queries.

Obviously these results would need to be refreshed as the target or people records change - - probably whenever a target is added/edited and refreshed periodically (hourly/nightly?) to pick up changes in people

Thanks for people's thoughts